# Web page is coming too large if user's system font size is increased (i.e. font-size: 150% as recommended by the windows)

Tags: html, css, font-scaling

I have created a web page using 14px as body font size. It is rendering properly in my system (windows font size set to 100%) but when someone else , whose windows font size is set to (150%) - as recommended by Windows, Web page is coming too large(everything is enlarged). Is there any way to resize (font scale) the page or manage the page so that content will come properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different font-scaling methods - such as `em` which relies on the container element (the body in your case). To my knowledge, this should alter the size of the font depending on the system font size, resolution etc.. Good luck.